# How to check browser is public-key credentials supported?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, webauthn

I am implementing **webauthn** using PHP, now I'm facing problem with how to detect browser is **public-key credentials** supported or not. If browser is supported **public-key credentials** then I have to start fingerprint registration procedure.

So is there any way we can detect browser **public-key credentials**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 if (typeof(PublicKeyCredential) != "undefined") {
   // Code here
 }
```

> The PublicKeyCredential interface provides information about a public
>   key / private key pair. It inherits from Credential, and was created
>   by the Web Authentication API extension to the Credential Management
>   API. Other interfaces that inherit from Credential are
>   PasswordCredential and FederatedCredential.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PublicKeyCredential

Comment: I have used this `if (window.PasswordCredential) {` condition. Inside this condition, I use this `navigator.credentials.get(` still, I can see some of the user's browsers report this error: `The user agent does not support public key credentials`. what could be the reason? Should I check for both PasswordCredential and PublicKeyCredential like this `if (window.PasswordCredential && typeof(PublicKeyCredential) != undefined)) {`

Answer (score 3):

I found one Google developer article and this JavaScript code work for me.

```
if (window.PublicKeyCredential) {
   // code here
}else{
   alert("public-key credentials not supported");
}
```

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/03/webauthn-credential-management

Comment: I would advise for guard style, `if (!window.PublicKeyCredential) { // code return }`